# i want the data that is in form component to be shown when pickup button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context

i want the data that is in form component to be shown when pickup button is clicked. the data from myvehicles to be entered inside the pickup component, when the yes or no button is clicked. i have tried like this but it doesnot work.

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import './Pickup.css'
import logo from './images/logo.png'
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import InfoYes from './InfoYes'
import InfoNo from './InfoNo'




function Pickup() {
    const [showInfoYes, setShowInfoYes] = useState(false);
    const [showInfoNo, setShowInfoNo] = useState(false);
    const history = useHistory()
    
    return (
        
        
      
        <div className="pickup">
        
  
            <div className="vehicles__navbar">

<Link to="/" className="header__link">
    <img
    className="navbar__logo"
    src={logo}
    alt="logo"
    />
</Link>

<button className="navbar__button" onClick={() => history.push('/')}>Logout</button>

</div>

            <div className="pickup__info">
            <h1 className="h1__pickup">do you want bluebook pickup service?</h1> 
            <div className="pickup__button">
            <button className="yes__button" onClick={() => setShowInfoYes(!showInfoYes)}>yes</button>
            <button className="no__button" onClick={() => setShowInfoNo(!showInfoNo)}>no</button>
            </div>
            {showInfoYes && <InfoYes setShowInfoYes={setShowInfoYes} />}            </div>
            {showInfoNo && <InfoNo setShowInfoNo={setShowInfoNo} />}  
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Pickup
```

Comment: Could you tell us WHAT doesn't work? The problem might come from your InfoYes or InfoNo components.

Comment: @jperl when i click the yes or no button a popup appears with h1 titles but without information i entered on previous state. i want to get the previous components states values and display inside popup while yes or no button is clicked.

Comment: at first i fill the form and click save button and save the values in state and i click next button and then pickup components loads which asks yes or no , i click yes or no any button i get popup with h1 like select vehicle , vehicle type , etc side by side value fetched from the state of previous form  component. plus i have updated the code and have provided codesandbox link.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-swirles-tipf3?file=/src/Pickup.js

Comment: pls read carefully and take a look,

Comment: I've seen your code through the link you provided and that's not the way to share data between components... InfoYes and InfoNo should receive the data they need through props not through imports!!!

Comment: how you said can you give demo in this codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-swirles-tipf3?file=/src/InfoYes.css

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to achieve this through conditional rendering.
Which involves if statements and true & false conditions.

Please look at this documentation to see how this works. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
(Reactjs.org has really great documentation, I really encourage you go through it.)

No where in your code, I see your state to be set TRUE for it to render.
You'll need to create an onClick handler to set this to true or false.

A quick example would be:

```
    const [userClicked, setUserClicked] = useState(false);
    
    { userClicked ? 

    ( <button onClick={() => setUserClicked(false)> No </button> 

   ) : ( 

     <button onClick={() => setUserClicked(true)> Yes </button> 
    
    )}
```

This is a shorthand of a ternary operator to produce an if/then statement in react.
It would be the easiest to accomplish your goal, although I do suggest that you research a little bit more on it!

`{userClicked ? ( ) : ( ) }`

You could also take out:

```
const [showInfoYes, setShowInfoYes] = useState(false);
const [showInfoNo, setShowInfoNo] = useState(false);
```

It's a bit redundant as you're trying to achieve something that could be done in a singular state.

Comment: no i dont want the condition as both yes and no buttons displays info only difference is one will have pickup value yes or no. the main problem is the inforamtion inside the vehicles i enter after clicking yes or no is not displaying when yes or no button is clicked.

Comment: Ah I see, as I said before, there's no where in your code that your state is being set to true. They're both firing false statements.

Comment: `setShowInfoYes(!showInfoYes)` that's the piece of code that toggles the state. Though it should be done in this way instead: setShowInfoYes(prevState => !prevState)

Comment: how you said can you give demo in this codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-swirles-tipf3?file=/src/InfoYes.js